# Почему мой код постоянно перезаписывает логин и пароль, а не заводит новый?

Tags: python, авторизация, регистрация, проверка

```
def choices():
print("Что делаем?")
choice = int(input("Для регистрации выберите - 1    Для входа в систему выбирете - 2 "))
if choice == 1:
   return getdetails()
elif choice == 2:
   return checkdetails()
else:
   raise TypeError

def getdetails():
    print("Напишите")
    name = input("Логин: ")
    password = input("Пароль: ")

    with open ("autoriz.txt","r") as file:
        if name in file:
            print("Такой аккаунт уже существует. Введите другие данные")
        else:
            file= open("autoriz.txt",'w')
            file.write(f"{name} {password} \n")
            print('Вы успешно зарегистрировались (Вы не видите "None") ')
    


def checkdetails():
    print("Напишите")
    name = str(input("Логин: "))
    password = str(input("Пароль: "))
    f = open("autoriz.txt",'r')
    info = f.read()
    info = info.split()
    if name in info:
        index = info.index(name) + 1
        usr_password = info[index]
        if usr_password == password:
            return "Вы успешно вошли в аккаунт, " + name
        else:
            return "Данные введены неверно"
    else:
        return "Данные не найдены. Пожалуйста, зарегистрируйтесь."


print(choices())
```

Comment: Потому что `file.write` пишет в один и тот же файл каждый раз заново?

Comment: Открывайте в режиме 'a',  а не 'w'  файл при записи пароля. Вообще хранить открытым текстом пароли небезопасно, обычно хранят хэши и делают проверку на совпадение хэша пароля введённого с записанный хэшем.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, но нам в курсовой работе казали для начала так сделать))

Comment: Но тут появилась еще одна проблема)
Он постоянно просто регистрирует новый аккаунт, даже если я введу уже существующие данные. Проверка почему-то не проходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно изменить:

```
file= open("autoriz.txt",'w')
```

Открывает как новый файл.

На:

```
file= open("autoriz.txt",'a')
```

Открывает для дополнительной записи.

Comment: совсем не помешало бы краткое объяснение сути предлагаемой замены.

Comment: Блин, такая глупая ошибка. Спасибо большое